# Solving equation for wifi password.

Tags: calculus, integration

I found this picture on Twitter and I'm curious is it solvable or not. For me, a first-year student with little math knowledge, it is just looks like a mess.

[image]

> Solve for the password :
>   $$ \frac{ \int u (u^2 +5)^{1/2}~du - 3 \int u (u^2 -5)^{-1/2}~   }{\displaystyle\int \frac{u ((u^2 +5)-3)}{\sqrt{u^2 +5}}~du}$$

Comment: Did you try inputting this formula into Wolfram Alpha? Also attempt substitution on the integrals.

Comment: I think the expression is supposed to be
$$
\frac{ \int u (u^2 +5)^{1/2}~du - 3 \int u (u^2 -5)^{-1/2}~du   }{\int \frac{u ((u^2 +5)-3)}{\sqrt{u^2 +5}}~du}
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need to know much of calculus,

$$\frac{u((u^2+5)-3)}{\sqrt{u^2+5}}=u(u^2+5)^{1/2}-3u(u^2+5)^{-1/2}.$$

My bet is that the "Pasword" is "one" or "1", assuming a typo ($-5$ instead of $+5$; also missing $du$), and assuming that the integration constants can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It's ridiculous. Numerator and denominator are same, if we more generalise the integration.. So,ans is 1

Comment: Isn't your answer the same as what Yves has written?

Comment: Problem lies in the constant of integration

Comment: They are quasi the same...